# Pop-up message using powershell

Tags: powershell

It's possible to display a pop-up message using PowerShell for remote users.
I try this:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("hello",0,"Done",0x1)
```

but this code display local on my PC the pop-up window, and I want to run the PowerShell script on my PC and the pop-up message to be displayed where "abcuser" is logged on.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, I know powershell remoting creates an individual session for example so it wouldn't appear to the logged on user. But have you considered just using the old fashioned NET SEND ?

Comment: @CBogdan You cannot do it via $wshell as it will never cross session boundary. User session and powershell remote session are _isolated_. To do UI-interaction between sessions either inject to user session via PSExec (or Task Scheduler) or use `net send` which is superseded by `msg.exe` in modern systems.

Answer (score 3):

Use this for Windows 7/10:

```
msg console /server:localhost "Test message"
```

This will display message to console user when called from Remote PowerShell session.

Instead of `console` you can put any active session name from `quser` output.

You can also do it remotely (that is from local session) - just replace `localhost` with user's PC name or IP. Althrough this requires TCP port 445 to be open and editing AllowRemoteRPC registry key in some cases. Sample:

```
msg * /server:192.168.0.1 "Hello!"
```

Comment: Not working. Getting error 5 for all IPs. The computers are visible in network